# How to do parameter passing for Creating N number or labels programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am doing an application where I am creating a LABELS programmatically..What my Requirement is I need to create some 10 LABELS programmatically, so only there Position and Text label changes. Instead of Writing the same function for every Label Thought of doing it By parameter passing, where only v need pass only the Label name and Position of the label...how to implement it?

//Below code shows creation of Labels With Different Names, instead I want to have one function and do parameter passing rather than creating a function for each label.

```
-(void)Vendorname

{ 

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,80,150,20)];
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    myLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x124F73);
    myLabel.text = @"Vendor Name";
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];

}

-(void)address

{

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,110,350,20)];
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    myLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x124F73);
    myLabel.text = @"84-21 Gwanheon dong,jungo-gu,seoul,south korea";
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];

}
```

Comment: so why can't you create a method like this? -
    -(void)addLabelWithText:(NSString*)text frame:(CGRect)frame;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UILabel*)createLabel:(CGRect)frame :(NSString*)labelTitle{
        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
        myLabel.text = labelTitle;     
        return [myLabel autorelease];
    }



[self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(50,80,150,20):@"ur Title"]];
```

Comment: i need to place  this code 
[self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(50,80,150,20)]:@"ur Title"]  in ViewDidLoad Method ?

Comment: You add this where u want to add label

Comment: its showing bad access...i placed [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(50,80,150,20)]:@"ur Title"]; in viewdidload method its showing createlabel method not found return  type Id

Comment: try this [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(50,80,150,20):@"ur Title"]];

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)createLabel:(NSString *)text :(CGRect)frame{

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
myLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x124F73);  
myLabel.text = text;     
[self.view addSubview:myLabel]; 
[myLabel release];    


}
```

call the above method...

```
[self createLabel:@"label1" :frame];
```

Comment: we need to cal the above method in ViewDidLoad?and what about frame?each label should be placed in different postion i mean x and y axis.....

Comment: yes you need to call it in viewDidLoad and you need to create a frame which will state its (x,y,height,width)parameters... like... CGRect frame = CGRectMake(190, 190, 100, 100);

Answer (score -1):

```
        try this one
        int x=50;
int y=80
        [self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(x,y,150,20) title:@"Vendore"]];

    -(UILabel*)createLabel:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString*)title{
            UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
            [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
            myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
            myLabel.text = title;     
            return [myLabel autorelease];
        }
```

Comment: ya But for creating next label Position and Label name Changes..where i need to create some Tables with same fontname,font,color etc.... only Change is Position and Lable Text...so how do we implement by parameter passing..so tat use one function and do parameter passing only by passing text name and position of the label

Comment: for this u only change x y position of label